# Замена полей в GroupBy LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Есть такой код:

```
var query = from data in db.GetTable<TableClass>()
                group data by new { data.Organisation, data.City } into result
                select new
                {
                    Organisation = result.Key.Organisation,
                    City = result.Key.City,
                    Quantity = result.Sum(i => i.Quantity),
                    Summa = result.Sum(i => i.Summa)
                };
```

Как можно сделать что бы можно было динамически менять поля по которым группируют. Например:

```
var query = from data in db.GetTable<TableClass>()
                    group data by new { data.Manager, data.Organisation, data.Date } into result
                    select new
                    {
                        Manager = result.Key.Manager;
                        Organisation = result.Key.Organisation,
                        Date = result.Key.Date,
                        Quantity = result.Sum(i => i.Quantity),
                        Summa = result.Sum(i => i.Summa)
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
group data by new { data.Manager, Organisation = condition ? data.Organisation : "" } into result
```

В зависимости от `condition` группировка будет по 1 полю или по 2.

Comment: На самом деле, это не очень хорошая идея - оптимизатор не сможет построить правильный план для подобных запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью библиотеки `System.Linq.Dynamic`

Вот что вышло:

```
            string groupingQuery = "new(City, Country)";
            string selectQuery = "Key.City, Key.Country";
            var query = db.GetTable<TableClass>().GroupBy(groupingQuery, "new(Quantity,Summa)")
                .Select($"new({selectQuery}, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity, Sum(Summa) as Summa)");
```

Формируем нужные строки, а дальше их вставляем в запрос.